# Strict aliasing rule in array

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

Is this fragment of code a violation of strict aliasing rule:

```
int main()
{
    short tab[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int* ps = (int*)(&tab[0]);
    int i = *ps;
}
```

I do know that if this was in the opposite way it would be a violation

```
int main()
{
    int tab[] = {1,2,3,4};
    short* ps = (short*)(&tab[0]);
    short s = *ps;
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe the cases are different? Also the code does not actually access any values, are you really asking about those exact pieces of code or something more involved?

Comment: AIUI, casting any pointer type to any other pointer type is a strict aliasing violation unless you are casting between a derived and base type, or between any pointer type and `void*`.

Comment: @cdhowie The cast isn't a violation. Accessing the stored value is. Also there are more exceptions than these two.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, I forgot to dereference pointers to really violate the rule and I think that this post apply to be considered as duplicate - all is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course that violates strict aliasing. The code is accessing values through a pointer of a different type, and it isn't `char*`.

```
int main()
{
    short tab[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int* ps = (int*)(&tab[0]);
    *ps = 3;
    if(tab[0] == 1) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is allowed to return 1 there. Because a write to *ps is a write to an `int` and according to strict aliasing rules an `int` pointer cannot possibly point to a `short`. Therefore the optimizer is allowed to see that the `tab` array is not modified, optimize out the `if` statement because it is always true, and rewrite the entire function to simply return 1.

Comment: Where exactly is he accessing the values?

Comment: @Columbo: He isn't which is why I added some things to the code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a pointer to another (arbitrary) pointer type, as long as it's not ill-formed, doesn't constitute a violation; But accessing the pointees value after dereferencing that pointer would be.

Your cast is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`, [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue v of type “pointer to `T1`” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<`*cv*
>   `T2*>(static_cast<`*cv* `void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout
>   types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than
>   those of `T1`, or if either type is void.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get undefined behaviour in both cases if you attempt to dereference the converted pointer.

Informally, this is because the alignments of the types might be different.

Using a union; with a longer type and an array of the shorter type is one safe way of converting data.

Comment: The pointer cast isn't UB. That's exactly what `reinterpret_cast` does. A strict aliasing violation happens when you try to access the stored value via the pointer.

Comment: The union trick is often compiler-supported. But it is still a technical aliasing violation.

Comment: You sure about that? I'll paste up some example code tomorrow when I'm back at work.